# ISP likes linux more than windows?

Tags: wireless-networking, internet, isp

I work for a company that installs wireless/wired networks for customers.  Recently we installed gigabit system for a customer, that gives 2-300mb to windows computers, and 800-900mb for linux machines.  All our hardware tested/replaced, verified working with gigabit.  This test is straight at the D-Marc.  What programming/hardware would have to be in place at the head end of things to cause this to happen?

Comment: It really depends on what you are testing, with how many connections, what window sizes etc. I would start with comparing TCP settings on the different operating systems and adding your findings to the question.

Comment: What exactly are you measuring and how exactly are you measuring it?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I am measuring the incoming internet speed, of which our customer is supposed to be getting 1Gbit, (realistically 800-900mb)

Comment: @SanderSteffann I am positive there is nothing different than normal w/my tcp settings(using my own laptop for tests), because it is used daily to check speeds, and gigabit has been tested with it just fine.  My question is mainly dealing with settings that would be set on the ISP side of things.  Thanks!

Comment: The ISP can't see the difference between packets sent by different operating systems. Check your settings. Different operating systems use different default settings, which will have a huge impact on performance.